# Labelling axes on a PolarPlot

Tags: plotting

Mathematica doesn't seem to be able to label axes properly on a `PolarPlot` or `PolarListPlot`. See for instance:

```
PolarPlot[theta, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"r", "theta"}]
```

[image]

Any thoughts? Do I just need to add this manually using `Text` in an `Epilog` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AxesLabel is only valid for the option PolarAxis->False. With theta running around a circle and r running along the radius it kind of hard to mark clearly. It seems there is no option in PolarPlot that is dedicated to this. My suggestion is using text and arrows.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's not as painful to use `Text` as I thought. Annoying though!

Comment: A primitive version is this:PolarPlot[theta, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 Epilog -> { Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, 2}}], Text["R", {1.5, 0.5}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 9.5}, {-2, 9.5}}], Text["theta", {1, 9.5}]}]

Comment: I agree. My primitve version needs adjusting for every plot. Making an genereal version is far more effort.